# Installing Windows Security updates on non-networked workstations

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have seen a number of similar questions, but all of them are either out of date, or presume an offline network, or offline servers.

We have a large number of remote locations, most of which do not have their own IT shops. Each of those locations has at least two and possibly many workstations that are not connected to any kind of network whatsoever. Those workstations are running Windows 10 Enterprise. None of those things is negotiable.

Two to four times a year, we prepare an update for our application. The remote locations retrieve that update via our secure web portal, load it on to a flash drive, and apply that update on each workstation. I would like to use that as an opportunity to also install any security or critical updates for Windows since the last update.

So far my best option I've seen is WSUS Offline, but it does not make it easy to do incremental updates and without that eventually the download size will become unreasonable. I have not used WSUS or SCCM, but it looks like they do not have the option to create an offline installer. The target workstations are very locked down, so in my ideal world I would like the resulting executable(s) to be signed by either Microsoft or us.

Are there any other options I should be looking at? We have no problems paying for an enterprise solution if available. Right now I'm seriously considering taking the source from WSUS Offline and modifying it to fit my needs, but I would rather not tie up my development resources.

Comment: Above what number of GB is unreasonable?

Comment: Do you know about http://catalog.update.microsoft.com?  You can download the patches from there bundled in MSU files.  It shouldn't be too hard to include a script to install them.  Only problem is, generally, microsoft doesn't know how to make a small patch.

Comment: I don't have a specific number in mind. The flash drives we are currently planning on are 16GB, but flash drives are cheap. The bigger issue is that some remote locations have some terrible internet connections. I'm pretty sure some of them have DSL connections, although they may choose not to participate.

Comment: I knew the updates could be downloaded individually, but I didn't realize they could be bundled that way. That could be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

With the newer patch model, everything has become cumulative, and that's why they are so large. They have essentially become a monthly per product service pack. So depending on which products you have loaded on these machines, you only need the most recent update for: (#1) The OS, and then whichever version of (#2) IE, (#3) .NET Framework, and maybe (#4) Office that is installed.

Example: If you're patching 2x a year in say January and June, you dont need to apply stuff from the other 10 months of the year because Jan 2018 replaces anything from 2017, and June 2018 replaces Feb-May 2018.

Answer (score 0):

http://catalog.update.microsoft.com

(Make sure you get the one for the correct OS and x86 or x64)
Type in the KB####### one at a time and add them to cart
When prompted for a folder browse to c:\updates

The Wusa.exe file is in the %windir%\System32 folder. The Windows Update Standalone Installer uses the Windows Update Agent API to install update packages.

```
for /R "C:\Updates\" %i in (*.msu) do wusa "%i" /quiet /norestart
```

I would suggest renaming the patches, by adding a 1,2,3, and etc to the beginning of the filename,  so they are installed in the correct order.  Either than or just have a bunch of wsu in the batch file.

```
wusa "package1.msu" /quiet /norestart
wusa "package2.msu" /quiet /norestart
wusa "package3.msu" /quiet /norestart
...
```

You could of course make a more intelligent script that checks for the presence of updates, and only applies the needed ones.

The only potential problem here updates may have mandatory reboots, and your script will have to handle that condition.  Also updates could fail to install which would require more error checking.

---

Another potential answer is full imaging.  You can use imagex, from microsoft, to capture windows into a wim file.  Then have a windows PE enviroment on the USB stick with the wim file.  Deploy the wimfile, reboot, and your done.

The advantage here is that you know all the patches are deployed properly.  The computer will be in a uniform configuration.

If the end user needs to store files I would suggest partition the hard drive into c: and d: then store all the user file on D: so you can re-image the C: drive at will.

The biggest downside is size, even if you clean up the image thoroughly it will be much larger. Maybe 16 or 32gb depends on how big your program is and how thoroughly you scrub the hard drive of unwanted files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the latest update cab `wsusscn2.cab` from here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=74689
2. Get the PowerShell module to manage updates, manually download the `.nupkg` https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate/2.2.0.2
3. Copy those two files to the USB you will use to move your updates to the computer.
4. Unzip the `.nupkg` in to the modules folder: `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` so that the final path looks like `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSWindowsUpdate` with the contents of the nupkg in that folder.
5. Import the module: `Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate`
6. Add the cab file from step 1. as a source of updates: `Add-WUOfflineSync -Path C:\wsusscan.cab` using the path where you put the cab file.
7. Get the `ServiceID` created in step 6 with: `Get-WUServiceManager`. This command lists all options and their GUIDs. The one you are looking for will have a name of `Offline Sync Service`
8. Install updates from that new source by citing the `ServiceID` from step 7 where I put `<GUID>`:

`Install-WindowsUpdate -ServiceID <GUID> -AcceptAll -AutoReboot`